# Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGSize' that accepts an argument list of type '(() -> _)' in Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgsize

I am working along with a Stanford course and am receiving this error:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGSize' that accepts an argument list of type '(() -> _)'
```

This course was taught just a couple months ago but was using Xcode 6.2 instead of Xcode 6.3. What do I need to do differently to correct this error?

This is lecture 12 - Dynamic Animation - http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

[image]

```
import UIKit

class DropItViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var gameView: UIView!

    var dropsPerRow = 10

    var dropSize = CGSize {
        let size = gameView.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(dropsPerRow)
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }

    @IBAction func drop(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        drop()
    }

    func drop() {
        var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: dropSize)
        frame.origin.x = CGFloat.random(dropsPerRow) * dropSize.width

        let dropView = UIView(frame: frame)
        dropView.backgroundColor = UIColor.random

        gameView.addSubview(dropView)
     }
    }

    private extension CGFLoat {
    static func random(max: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(max))

    }
    }

    private extension UIColor {
    class var random: UIColor {
        switch arc4random()%5 {
        case 0: return UIColor.greenColor()
        case 1: return UIColor.blueColor()
        case 2: return UIColor.orangeColor()
        case 3: return UIColor.redColor()
        case 4: return UIColor.purpleColor()
        default: return UIColor.blackColor()

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You wrote CGFloat wrong. It is not CGF**L**oat but CGF**l**oat.

Comment: Thank you, I am still pretty new to this and I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you typed CGFloat incorrectly. It is CGF**l**oat not CGF**L**oat.

For the second part, change '=' to ':' in dropSize:

```
var dropSize : CGSize {
    let size = gameView.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(dropsPerRow)
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Also, this is the first time I have seen '=' used instead of ':' in Swift, since its release...

Answer (score 2):

And it is code from your course:

```
var dropSize: CGSize {
    let size = gameView.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(dropsPerRow)
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

You only need check your code and code from course and it help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the first error, you need to use a constructor to create your **dropSize**. I would recommend adding your own:

```
static func calculateDropSize(width: CGFloat, dropsPerRow: UInt32) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGFloat(width / CGFloat(dropsPerRow))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Then, you would rewrite that line to be:

```
var dropSize = MyClass.calculateDropSize(gameView.bounds.size.width, dropsPerRow: dropsPerRow)
```

You could add that function as an extension of CGSize but that would be undesirable from an Object Oriented standpoint.

Your second error just needs to be cast:

```
var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGFloat(dropSize))
```

Your third error, as Gasim commented, **CGFloat** is typo'd:

```
private extension CGFloat {
```

Comment: I am going to have to disagree with you because why would you cast a CGSize to CGSize? He has a cast issue because he actually has a syntax issue: He typed `=` instead of `:`. If he went with you path to solve this problem, he would still not need to cast to CGFloat...